# how to extract maximum and minimum value from column 1 and column 2

Tags: awk, sed, numeric-data

Dear all I have a **big** data file lets say **file.dat**, it contains two columns

e.g file.dat (showing few rows)

```
    0.0000  -23.4334
    0.0289  -23.4760
    0.0578  -23.5187
    0.0867  -23.5616
    0.1157  -23.6045
    0.1446  -23.6473
    0.1735  -23.6900
    0.2024  -23.7324
    0.2313  -23.7745
    0.2602  -23.8162
    0.2892  -23.8574
    0.3181  -23.8980
    0.3470  -23.9379
    0.3759  -23.9772
    0.4048  -24.0156
    0.4337  -24.0532
    0.4627  -24.0898
    0.4916  -24.1254
note: data file has a blank line at the end of the file
```

### Expected results

I want to find/extract the maximum and minimum from both the column
e.g
column-1

```
max - 0.4916
min - 0.0000
```

similarly
column-2

```
max - -23.4334
min - -24.1254
```

### Incomplete solution (not working for column-2)

**For Column-1**

```
awk 'BEGIN{min=9}{for(i=1;i<=1;i++){min=(min<$i)?min:$i}print min;exit}' file.dat 
0.0000
```

```
cat file.dat | awk '{if ($1 > max) max=$1}END{print max}'
0.4916
```

**for column-2**

```
awk 'BEGIN{min=9}{for(i=2;i<=2;i++){min=(min<$i)?min:$i}print min;exit}' file.dat
-23.4334

cat file.dat | awk '{if ($2 > max) max=$2}END{print max}'
**no output showing**
```

### Problem

Please help me to find the min and max value from column-2
**note: data file has a blank line at the end of the file**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue in your code,

```
awk 'BEGIN{min=9}{for(i=2;i<=2;i++){min=(min<$i)?min:$i}print min;exit}' file.dat
```

... is that you immediately `exit` after processing the first line of input.  Your middle block there need to be triggered for *every* line.  Then, in an `END` block, you can print the values that you have found.  You do this in another code snippet:

```
awk '{if ($1 > max) max=$1}END{print max}'
```

Another issue is that you initialize `min` with a magic number (9 in the first code that I quoted, and 0 in the second piece; variables that are not explicitly initialized has the value 0 if you use them in calculations). If this magic number does not fall within the range of numbers in the actual data, then the calculated min and/or max values will be wrong.  It is better to initialize both min and max to some value found in the data.

To keep track of *both* min and max values, you need two variables, and both of these needs to be checked against the data in the file for every line, to see whether they need updating.

As `awk` supports arrays, it would be natural to use arrays for `min` and `max`, with one array element per column.  This is what I have done in the code below.

---

Generalized to any number of columns:

```awk
NF == 0 {
        # Skip any line that does not have data
        next
}

!initialized {
        # Initialize the max and min for each column from the
        # data on the first line of input that has data.
        # Then immediately skip to next line.

        nf = NF

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
                max[i] = min[i] = $i

        initialized = 1
        next
}

{
        # Loop over the columns to see if the max and/or min
        # values need updating.

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i) {
                if (max[i] < $i) max[i] = $i
                if (min[i] > $i) min[i] = $i
        }
}

END {
        # Output max and min values for each column.

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
                printf("Column %d: min=%s, max=%s\n", i, min[i], max[i])
}
```

Given this script and the data in the question:

```
$ awk -f script.awk file
Column 1: min=0.0000, max=0.4916
Column 2: min=-24.1254, max=-23.4334
```

The condition `NF == 0` for the first block (which is executed for all lines) is to ensure that we skip blank lines. The test means "if there are zero fields (columns) of data on this line".  The variable `initialized` will be zero from the start (logically *false*), but will be set to one (logically *true*) as soon as the first line that has data is read.

The `nf` variable is initialized to `NF` (the number of fields) on the line that we initialize the `min` and `max` values from.  This is so that the output in the `END` block works even if the last line has zero fields.

Comment: Hmmm, what can I come up next to top that ... ;)

Comment: @AdminBee Well, there's currently a bug I'm fixing... (done)

Comment: @AdminBee Yours is more compact, but I've always favored the use of whitespace to make code readable.

Comment: Yeah, I can relate to that very much! At some point I skipped commenting the code, but actually that _is_ one of the relevant parts here, so that people can not only copy but understand the solution ...

Comment: thank you @Kusalananda for your fully explained code. I really appreciate your code.
thanks for help :)

Comment: The code is not generic in the sense that the number of fields processed is fixed to the number of fields found on the first line. It could be done better.

Comment: @Isaac You could just have a block at the top saying `NF > nf { nf = NF }` for that if you wanted.

Comment: @Kusalananda No, you attempt is too shallow. The point is not (only) to know how many fields there are, but to get max and min even if the number of fields change. Your answer fails (even with the modification you are proposing). Try the example file in my answer.

Comment: @Isaac Yeah, you need to initialize the new min/max values too, and then use `NF`, ok. I see, well that's interesting. I'll leave my answer as it is i think as there's nothing wrong with it. It's valid for any number of columns and it covers the case in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can combine all instructions into one `awk` program:

```
awk 'NR==1{min1=max1=$1;min2=max2=$2}\
     NR>1 {if ($1<min1) {min1=$1} else if ($1>max1) {max1=$1};\
            if ($2<min2) {min2=$2} else if ($2>max2) {max2=$2}; }\
     END{printf("Column1 min: %f\nColumn1 max: %f\nColumn2 min: %f\nColumn2 max:%f\n",min1,max1,min2,max2)}' file.dat
```

This will initialize the minimum and maximum values for both columns with the respective values of the first row (rule with condition `NR==1`), and then scan the successive rows to see if the values are larger than the current maximum/smaller than the current minimum, respectively (rule with condition `NR>1`).

At the end of file (rule with condition `END`), it prints the result.

**Notice** that this assumes *there are no empty lines*. If there are, you have to replace the `NR>1` condition with `NR>1 && NF>0`. If there can be empty lines *before the first one*, use

```
awk '!init && NF>0 {init=1; min1=max1=$1; min2=max2=$2} \
     init==1 && NF>0 {if ($1<min1) {min1=$1} else if ($1>max1) {max1=$1};\
                      if ($2<min2) {min2=$2} else if ($2>max2) {max2=$2}; }\
     END{printf("Column1 min: %f\nColumn1 max: %f\nColumn2 min: %f\nColumn2 max:%f\n",min1,max1,min2,max2)}' file.dat
```

This will use a variable `init` to check if a non-empty line was already found, and use the contents of the first non-empty line to pre-set the current maximum/minimum for both columns. Only if `init` is set (after this initialization) are (non-empty) lines considered for entering that statistic.

As a general remark, you never need to `cat` a file and pipe the result into `awk`.

Comment: Thanks a lot It is working like a charm:).
compact and understandable.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`datamash`](https://savannah.gnu.org/projects/datamash/) and `printf`:

```
for f in 1 2 ; do  printf 'Column #%s\nmax - %s\nmin - %s\n\n' $f \
                   $(datamash -W max $f min $f < file.dat); done
```

...or without a loop:

```
printf 'Column #%s\nmax - %s\nmin - %s\n\n' \
       $(datamash -W max 1 min 1 max 2 min 2 < file.dat | 
         tr -s '\t' '\n' | paste - - | nl)
```

Output of either:

```
Column #1
max - 0.4916
min - 0

Column #2
max - -23.4334
min - -24.1254
```

Comment: For two items a `for` loop isn't really necessary.  It's more efficient to call `datamash max 1 min 1 max 2 min 2` once, but the `printf` formatting would be gnarlier then...

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
awk  '{if (max == "") max=$2 ; else if ($2 > max) max=$2}END{print max}' file
awk  '{if (min == "") min=$2 ; else if ($2 < min) min=$2}END{print min}' file
```

Comment: 2nd command not working (for min value)

Comment: Because last empty line. I suggest to add an `if`: `awk '{if (NF>1) {if (min == "") min=$2 ; else if ($2 < min) min=$2}}END{print min}' file`

Comment: thanks, @Cyrus for help. it is working well now.:) :)

Answer (score 1):

This for col 1 ( It calculate avg max and min )

```
sort -n -k 1 file |awk '{SUM+=$1 ; if ( NR == 1) MIN=$1}  END{print "Average - "SUM/NR, "Min time - "MIN,"Max Time - "$1}'
```

this for col 2

```
sort -n -k 2 file |awk '{SUM+=$1 ; if ( NR == 1) MIN=$1}  END{print "Average - "SUM/NR, "Min time - "MIN,"Max Time - "$1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues on your code:

- You should not `exit` until all the input has been processed. In fact, an exit is not needed.
- The first line needs to be used to initialize the values of max and min. If the value of a field on the first line is negative, a test like `min > $1` will be false as min doesn't have a value yet (so it defaults to `0` numerically).
- Both max and min could be found in one call to awk.

## Generic

A generic solution for any number of fields (within reason) at any line (the number of fields need not be constant) which only assumes that an empty field contains a null (`""`) and that accepts all the values that awk accepts (usually strings are converted to `0`) is this:

```
awk '
{
       if(nf<NF){nf=NF};              # find the max number of fields
                                      # to print at the end
       for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){ 
                           f=$i+0;    # convert each field to a number
                           # Either initialize (if empty)
                           # or capture max and min.
                           if(max[i]==""||max[i]<f){ max[i]=f }
                           if(min[i]==""||min[i]>f){ min[i]=f }
                         }
}
END{
       for(i=1;i<=nf;i++){print i,min[i],max[i]}
}' file
```

On this short file (an example):

```
    0.1735  -23.6900
    0.2024  -23.7324
    0.2313  -23.7745
    0.2602  -23.8162  23 -12 PREC
    0.2892  -23.8574  46 -23
    0.3181  -23.8980
```

The output will be:

```
1 0.1735 0.3181
2 -23.898 -23.69
3 23 46
4 -23 -12
5 0 0
```

For your file it will print:

```
1 0 0.4916
2 -24.1254 -23.4334
```